# I cut/pasted a folder into a local repository mid-clone - the clone failed and the folder disappeared. Is the folder I pasted gone forever?

Tags: windows, git, git-clone, file-recovery, undelete

I wanted to put my local code into a GitHub repository.

I created a repo on GitHub and tried cloning with HTTPS.
The clone was taking a moment but the folder was created on my laptop so I decided to cut/paste my local code into the local repo folder.

Well, the clone ended up failing and the repo folder just disappeared, along with all of its contents.
The folder I added to the local repo also disappeared.
I can't even find it in the recycling bin. Is it gone forever?

Comment: Probably. Good thing you have backups. You have backups, right?

Comment: You made me chuckle knittl, but be kind, we've all been there without backups.

Comment: Specifically, what does "the clone ended up failing" mean?

Comment: Yes: when you run `git clone`, the first step that Git does is make a new empty directory (or use an empty directory that you tell it to use) to hold a new empty repository (the `.git` sub-directory). If the clone step fails, Git removes the empty directory it created, and to do that, it has to remove all of its content first. In a somewhat nasty bug—long fixed now—Git used to remove that empty directory even if `git clone` was using one you supplied yourself!

Comment: It wasn't too bad of a bug since `git clone` wouldn't run if the directory you supplied *wasn't* empty, but it was clearly wrong, and resulted in losing folders you moved into that initially-empty directory: i.e., exactly the loss you've just experienced.

Answer (score 0):

Next time:

- make sure you have [installed `gh`](https://github.com/cli/cli#installation), the GitHub CLI
- create a repository locally where your code is
- publish to GitHub (that will create the remote repository)

That way, no clone, no hazardous code migration.

The command to create the remote repository is (after a [gh auth login](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_auth_login)):
[`gh repo create`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_repo_create).

> Inside a git repository, and with no arguments, `gh` will automatically create a repository on GitHub on your account for your current directory, using the directory name.